# Weird behaviour from SKPhysicsBody applyImpulse

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

So i have a few balls dropping from the sky, touching a paddle.

The paddle applies

```
ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 200))
```

to the balls.

9 out of 10 times, the ball bounces back up 1/4 of the screen.

1 out of 10 times, the ball goes super crazy and flies as if applyImpulse would've been (0, 1000)~

Also!
When the balls return back from the first bounce, and get .applyImpulse once again, they fly all the way to the top. Much much higher than the first applyImpulse. (Happens on all balls, first bounce: 1/4 screen. Second bounce: 3.9/4 screen.)

Why is this?

I would like the balls to stay consistent, i want every bounce to have the same force.

```
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: ball.size.width, height: ball.size.height))
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue | PhysicsCategory.boss.rawValue
    ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.noCollision.rawValue
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyA : contact.bodyB
    let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask >= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyA : contact.bodyB

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue ==  PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue &&
        secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue == PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue) {
            CollisionWithBar(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, ball: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }

}

func CollisionWithBar(bar: SKSpriteNode, ball: SKSpriteNode) {
    ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 200))
    NSLog("Ball hit Bar")

}
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code pertaining to where you are applying the impulse?

Comment: Have you considered letting the physics engine handle the bouncing effect (collision) instead of applying an impulse when a contact is made?

Comment: @TrentSartain updated my post with the code :)

Comment: @0x141E i'm not sure how thats done, is it possible to create an effect where the balls keeps an consistent bounce-height? I want one ball to fall from the sky, bounce up, fall down, bounce upp, fall down - forever. With the same height :)

Comment: If the ball is just going to bounce up and down without moving left and right, you can set `ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1` and not worry about applying the impulse.  Is that what you were thinking @0x141E?  Alternatively, you can set the ball's velocity to 0 right before you apply the impulse to offset any other speed interactions.

Comment: @TrentSartain yes, but the ball's x position needs to be constrained with an `SKConstraint`. Your approach should work as well.

Comment: ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)
ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 115)) work very nice. Thanks! :)

Comment: I suspect you can achieve the same in one step by setting to y-velocity to a positive value with `ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: velY)`.

Answer (score 0):

Before typing `ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 200))`, try typing `ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,0)`
This will reset the velocity of the ball so that (hopefully) it jumps back to the same height.